# How to float a DoesNotAcceptFocus window on top that over another fullscreen application in xmonad enviroment

Tags: qt, debian, window, fullscreen, xmonad

My problem :

A project , inlcude tow excution application that run in xmonad enviroment on debian10 .
One( name App_A  ) is a full screen exe .  The other one ( name App_B , build by Qt ) is hide normally , and only show out by user iput like a mouse right-key menu.

Currently , App_B  make a window to show camera video , this window should show up always , floating on top , and can't accept focus.

I set its attributes:

```
this->setWindowFlags(    Qt::Tool 
                       | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint 
                       | Qt::FramelessWindowHint  
                       | Qt::WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus 
                        //WA_X11DoNotAcceptFocus
                    ) ;

//this->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
setWindowModality( Qt::WindowModal ) ;
```

These settings work fine on MS windows 10  and debian10' Xfce desktop.

Now we customize the debian10 to a certain extent , the xmonad and our project is startup by poweron , and the xmonad just run as a window manager to manage our App_A and App_B at backgroud .

But , when run in this xmonad enviroment on debian10, the camera windows is always stay under the App_A , and can't not show up . But other windows of App_B can be show normally.

What is the key issuse ? Can this be resolved by only set the windows attributes in App_B , or it is due to the defect of xmonad ?

Comment: I think it's due to the window being floating. The bug is documented here: https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/issues/106

Comment: Thanks.  It is possobily cased by the windows show up sequence . I made the camera video windows show up after the App_A (full screen one ) show up ,  then it can stay on top .